# Changing Visual Studio 2008 New Tab Position

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tabs

One of my pet peeves ever since Visual Studio 2005 (behavior is unchanged in VS 2008) came out was the placement of the new tabs when opened. These opened on the left of current tabs which was the opposite of where new tabs opened in Visual Studio 2003 and beyond.

In my opinion opening new tabs to the left of current tabs is counter-intuitive... Most tabbed applications including Firefox and IE7 open new tabs to the right. My question is, is there a configuration setting or hack to make tab opening behave like it did in Visual Studio 2003?

Answer (score 5):

** Not actually for VS 2008 - Only adding this here because it's the top hit on goog **

To set up tabs on the right for VS 2010

[Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Documents and select the "Insert documents to the right of existing tabs" option.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/16/the-best-of-visual-studio-2010-insert-documents-to-the-right-of-existing-tabs.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com) (developed by me) add-in for Visual Studio 2008 opens tabs on the right, adds multiple rows of tabs and much more.

Comment: Just FYI: Tabs Studio is commercial software and not a free add-in.

Comment: Not the best answer as the OP was asking if this is possible via the settings or via a hack.