# Visual Studio 2008 tab opening order

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I find the order in which vs2008 opens tabs very annoying.  I have tried looking at the options, but can't find any options to customise the order in which tabs are opened.  For example, at the moment, if I open a new files, the tab opens to the absolulte left side of all tabs.  Is it possible to set it up for new tabs to be opened to the right of the active tab, or the right of the right most tab?

I have seen this question, but this just provides a link to commercial software: [Changing Visual Studio 2008 New Tab Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623540/changing-visual-studio-2008-new-tab-position)

I want to know if there is an option built in to vs2008 do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VS2010, it's Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Documents -> Insert documents to the right of existing tabs.

Don't know for sure if that's in 2008, though.

Comment: Seems to be missing from 2008, hoping it's placed under a different dialog.